# PHP authentication integration with WOS2 Identity Server

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Actually, I have a CakePHP application that authenticates with SimpleSAML using WSO2 Identity Server (it redirects to WSO2IS login page). I need to create a page in my application and send the informations to WSO2IS to authenticate the user. How can I do it? I didn't found any example/documentation about it.
I followed this [tutorial](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/SAML2+IdP+with+SimpleSAMLphp+Service+Provider).

Files in simplesaml:
config/authsources.php

```
<?php
$config = array(
    'wso2-sp' => array(
        'saml:SP',
        'entityID' => 'IntranetSP', // I supposed that it is the ID of my Service Provider
        'idp' => 'https://soa.rw1.local:9443/samlsso'
    )
);

?>
```

metadata/saml20-idp-remote.php

```
<?php

$metadata['https://soa.rw1.local:9443/samlsso'] = array(

    'name' => array(

        'en' =>  'WSO2 IS',

        'no' =>  'WSO2 IS',

    ),

    'description'   =>  'Login with WSO2 IS SAML2 IdP.',

    'SingleSignOnService'  =>  'https://soa.rw1.local:9443/samlsso',  

    'SingleLogoutService'  =>  'https://soa.rw1.local:9443/samlsso',

    'certFingerprint'      =>  '6bf8e136eb36d4a56ea05c7ae4b9a45b63bf975d'



);

?>
```

In my Wso2 IS:

```
Service provider Configuration:

Service Provider Name: IntranetSP
Local & Outbound Authentication Configuration/Request Path Authentication Configuration: basic-auth
```

Comment: You can follow [1]  for setup sso Identity Server with simple sample php  [1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/SAML2+IdP+with+SimpleSAMLphp+Service+Provider

Comment: Most of the authenticators doing the same work so you can refer other custom authenticators[1] [1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ISCONNECTORS/Identity+Server+Authenticators+and+Connectors

Comment: @IsuraDilharaKarunaratne yes, I used this example and it's working.. My problem is that I need to create a PHP login page (it's easy) and send to WSO2 the information to authenticate.. Actually, the login's page is in WSO2, so, My PHP application is redirecting the user to a WSO2 login page to do the complete authentication.

Answer (score 0):

In your service provider configuration, under local and outbound authentication configuration, configure SP to use request path authentication.For more information about doing this, please follow [this](http://xacmlinfo.org/2015/02/12/sso-without-identity-provider-login-page/).

Following is a java code where you can send the request from a client.

```
@Test(alwaysRun = true, description = "Test login success")
public void testLoginSuccess() throws Exception {
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(TRAVELOCITY_SAMPLE_APP_URL + "/samlsso?SAML2.HTTPBinding=HTTP-POST");
    List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<>();
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", adminUsername));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", adminPassword));
    request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
    String line;
    String samlRequest = "";
    String secToken = "";

    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.contains("name='SAMLRequest'")) {
            String[] tokens = line.split("'");
            samlRequest = tokens[5];
        }
        if (line.contains("name='sectoken'")) {
            String[] tokens = line.split("'");
            secToken = tokens[5];
        }
    }
    EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity());
    request = new HttpPost(isURL + "samlsso");
    urlParameters = new ArrayList<>();
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sectoken", secToken));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("SAMLRequest", samlRequest));
    request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));
    response = client.execute(request);
    String samlResponse = "";
    rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.contains("name='SAMLResponse'")) {
            String[] tokens = line.split("'");
            samlResponse = tokens[5];
        }
    }
    Base64 base64Decoder = new Base64();
    samlResponse = new String(base64Decoder.decode(samlResponse))
    EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity());
}
```

You should be able to achieve this in PHP by sending the same requests.

But if your requirement is to change the login page, you can customize wso2 IS login page as mentioned [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Customizing+the+Authentication+Endpoint) without using your own page. If your requirement is this, I recommend you to do this as this will make your life much easier.

Comment: But how can I apply this in my PHP application? I'm already using a configured SP (I'm using WSO2IS 5.0.0)

Comment: Is it not possible for you to update the SP, you need to enable request path authentication in your SP, otherwise user will have to enter credential in IS sso login page.

Comment: I readed the link, but there is no explanation about how to configure the simplesaml in php, only how to configure in IS. I added in IS a service provider, like in the tutorial (added the basic-auth in Request Path Auth Conf - Local & Out...), but now, I don't know how can I configure my simplesaml. I will edit my question, putting my conf files